# How to capture old value and set it back on cancel using javascript

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a text field from which I am calling a function on `onChange` event. I am throwing a confirm window here when the value in that textfield is changed. If cancel is clicked( in confirm window), the old value must get set back into the text field. If proceed or ok is clicked, the new value should be retained.
I have been trying this for a long time but am unable to retain the old value.

Eg:
Before onchange, val in text field ='first';
onChange event, val changed to 'second', confirm window opens, if ok selected text field should have second and if cancel is selected 'first' should be present in the text field.

```
function onChangeOfValue(input){
    //var oldValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    document.getElementById(input).onchange = function(){
    var newValue = this.value;
    alert("newVal is--->"+newValue);
    if(document.getElementById(input) != null && document.getElementById(input) != '' 
    && !confirm("Do you want to continue?")){

    // this.input=oldValue;
        return false;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: you're looking for `defaultValue`.

Comment: Looking for the value present in that textfield, before a change is being tried.

Comment: i use defaultValue to store my oldValue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that form controls have a *defaultValue* property that is the default value (surprisingly). You can use this property to store the previous value of the input, or to return the value to the previous value.

So putting together the suggestions you've been given, the following function is passed a reference to the element and asks the user if they want to keep the current value. If they answer yes, then the *defaultValue* of the input is set to the current *value*. If the users says no (i.e. cancel), then the *value* is reset to the *defaultValue*.

Note that this approach will overwrite the original *value* of the input, so if you reset the form, the input's *value* will be reset to the current *defaultValue*.

```
<script>
function onChangeOfValue(element) {
  var oldValue = element.defaultValue;
  var newValue = element.value;
  if (window.confirm('do you really want to change the value to ' + newValue + '?')) {
    element.defaultValue = newValue;
  } else {
    element.value = element.defaultValue;
  } 
}
</script>

<input onchange="onChangeOfValue(this);">
```

This approach will work for any number of inputs in the same page and form.

Comment: +1 from me - not sure who downvoted.  Curious though, does defaultValue work in older browsers?  I mean, obviously you can always set a property like that in code, but if you do `<input defaultValue='foo' />` will foo still show up in the textbox in IE8, and show up as the initial value of element.defaultValue?

Comment: Ahh - I feel silly - defaultValue picks up whatever value you render the input with.  Neat.  Still not sure if it works in IE8 - I guess jsFiddle doesn't play well with it

Comment: The *defaultValue* property has been around forever, it's very well supported.

Comment: sure it is the right answer.. but to be passive aggressive about it?

Answer (score 6):

I would use a closure to keep track of the last value:

```
(function(){ 
    var oldValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    document.getElementById(input).onchange = function(){
        var newValue = this.value;
        alert("newVal is--->"+newValue);
        if(document.getElementById(input) != null 
            && document.getElementById(input) != '' 
            && !confirm("Do you want to continue?")){

            this.value = oldValue;
            return false;
        } else {
            oldValue = this.value;
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: I dont know what closure is(novice to JS). As of now, onChange of that textfield will call a 'onChangeOfValue' function. You want me to add the above code in that ? It will automatically capture the old value ? I doubt that.

Comment: A closure basically means that a function has access to the context that existed when it was invoked.  I'm saying replacing your onchange handler with what I have should get you what you want

Comment: Suppose textfield id is 'home', then var oldValue = document.getElementById("home"); will capture the oldValue before change ?

Comment: It should - read the code closely - oldValue is assigned the new value of the input as the last line of the handler, assuming it was not reverted to oldValue

Comment: aaah... It was oldVal="first" initially and thats why I added 2nd comment. ;) It is working now... Thanks for the knowledge & time adam

Comment: This approach will only work for one input, since you can only store one value. If you want to store more, you'll need to adopt a scheme to store values for multiple inputs.

Comment: There's a problem. After page load, there is some value in the text field. When I change it the first time, it is not going inside `document.getElementById(input).onchange = function(){`, and the value is being changed to whatever we give, without any confirm window. From second time, it is going inside the onChange function and confirm is coming up

Comment: @AnujBalan - not sure - put an alert first thing inside of the event handler and make sure it's being called at all.  Then check how and where the handler is being added

Comment: It is not called inside the handler first time at all. onChange of that textfield, the function I wrote is called but it is not going inside the closure function which you gave.