# Cancelling the onChange event of a dijit/form/FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, onchange, dijit.form

I need to be able cancel the onChange when a user tries to change value in FilteringSelect depending on if another action has made the information dirty or not.

I have tried to use the FilteringSelect's undo() method, but it's not working. I've tried aspect.before for the onChange event, but that seems to be hooked too late since the control has already got the new value. I tried to hook to the method that calls onChange, but have not been able to find that method.

How do I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Once the value is set to this widget, the value of "_lastDisplayedValue" also updates. So, undo is not apt for this case.

If the onChange event handler on this widget need to be detached, based on some conditions, "_onChangeActive" private flag can be made use. This is not supposed to be used by programmers explicitly and is for internal purpose of the widget. But, for this case, this can give a hack.

Set _onChangeActive=false, and the handler will be detached. But do not forget to reset it to true again, else, onChange function does not work, if this is set to false.

e.g:

```
    var widget = dijit.byId('widgetId');
    widget.set('_onChangeActive',false);
    widget.set('value',newValue); //onChange handler function does not run
    //not just programmatic, 
    //even if user tries to select, when onChangeActive=false this works
    widget.set('_onChangeActive',true);
    //now the onChange is resumed back
```

Comment: If I detach the onchange eventhandler, how do I know when then user tries to change the control?

Comment: It is not actually detached.. The flag will return the function in the first statement itself. If u reset the flag("_onChangeActive") to true again, onChange will work again. This flag is just like a switch to control.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried 'widget.set("_onChangeActive",false);' but after that 'widget.on("Change", function(e){...});' doesn't run.

Comment: yes. when you want that onChange to work again, reset back to true. ( I suggested this because, you said that, only based on some condition, the onChange should run. So, when that condition becomes true, set this flag to true too.

Comment: This is the story - The user changes the FilteringSelect. If a certain condition is true, I need to ask the user if he wants to continue changing the FilteringSelect. If so, everything i fine, but if he does not want to continue, I need to revert the FilteringSelect to the state before the onChange fired. 

If I do this at the onChange event, it's already too late, since the FilteringSelect has already changed.

Comment: Ok. In this case, you need to maintain the old value in separate field or as an extra attribute(for eg:oldValue) in this field. onChange function should update it accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931691/how-to-capture-old-value-and-set-it-back-on-cancel-using-javascript
Check out the 2nd answer (by Adam) in this. Thats a perfect one for your case.